# Deleting rows in a table a chunk at a time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, delete-row

I have a single-column table `Ids`, which whose column ID is of type `uniqueidentifier`. I have another table `MyTable` which has an ID column as well as many other columns. I would like to delete rows from `MyTable` 1000 at a time, where the ID from `MyTable` matches an ID in `Ids`.

```
WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN
    DELETE t FROM (SELECT TOP 1000 ID FROM Ids) d INNER JOIN MyTable t ON d.ID = t.ID;
    IF @@ROWCOUNT < 1 BREAK;
    WAITFOR DELAY @sleeptime; -- some time to be determined later
END
```

This doesn't seem to work though. What should the statement actually be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Delete from MyTable 
Where ID in 
   (select top 1000 t.ID 
    from Ids t inner 
    join MyTable d on d.Id = t.Id)
```

Comment: Will this perform well? The database I'm working on will be quite large.

Comment: That is not a straight forward question to answer.  I would make sure your ID is indexed to start with.  But generally, this should work efficiently.

Comment: Actually, won't this keep selecting the same top 1000 ID repeatedly from Ids, since I'm only deleting from MyTable?

Comment: well, once the first 1000 are deleted, they will no longer be selected in the next iteration.

Comment: If the Id columns are indexed it would probably be OK, but I would opt for E J Brennan's answer for safety

Comment: @northpole, but they are being deleted from MyTable, not from Ids. won't Ids not change from iteration to iteration?

Comment: @Nick - ID is the attribute, MyTable is the table, yes.  So when you delete, the next 'select top' statement will not have those previously deleted IDs in the resultset.

Comment: I have just edited to include an inner join to ensure that you are only deleting Ids that match up.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @BatchSize INT
SET @BatchSize = 100000

WHILE @BatchSize <> 0
BEGIN 
   DELETE TOP (@BatchSize) t
    FROM [MyTable] t
    INNER JOIN [Ids] d ON d.ID=t.ID
    WHERE ????
   SET @BatchSize = @@rowcount 
END
```

Has the benefit that the only variable you need to create is the size, as it uses it for the WHILE loop check. When the delete gets below 100000, it will set the variable to that number, on the next pass there will be nothing to delete and the rowcount will be 0... and so you exit. Clean, simple, and easy to understand. Never use a CURSOR when WHILE will do the trick!

Comment: There's usually one extra iteration here though.  How about while 1=1 and break if @@rowCount < @BatchSize at the end.

Comment: Not the worst suggestion, but I hate doing a no-op while loop and then an if to escape.  I guess you could avoid the extra interation most of the time with `WHILE @BatchSize = 100000`. you'd only have an extra iteration if you had an exact multiple of 100000.  We mostly use this with a count of 4500 to avoid table-locking when purging old data. one extra loop when we're doing a few hundred never hurt. Nice catch tho, @crokusek!

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```
set rowcount 1000
delete from mytable where id in (select id from ids)
set rowcount 0  --reset it when you are done.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx

Comment: true, but it applies to the version that comes after SQL-2012, so likely will work for some time.

Comment: At least remind the user to clear that setting... if they reuse a terminal session or have a large script things will go really wrong from this step forward!

Answer (score 0):

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable mt JOIN IDs i ON mt.ID = t.ID)
BEGIN

DELETE TOP (1000) FROM MyTable
FROM MyTable mt JOIN IDS i ON mt.ID = i.ID

--you can wait if you want, but probably not necessary
END
```

--Sorry for the quick post; was in a hurry :)

The DELETE statement in SQL Server supports two FROM clauses; the first FROM identifies the table that is having rows deleted, and the second FROM clause is used for JOINS.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx

Comment: edit your answer, I don't think is correct but the approach is right. WHY? repetition of `FROM MyTable`

Comment: Also `SELECT TOP 1 FROM` is missing something.